# Export BibleGatway page content in markdown format

Tags: script, markdown

#### Description

When browsing Bible Gateway show a textinput field with a markdown formatted copy of the current page for easy copy/paste into SE questions and answers. This is especially useful for users of the [Christianity](http://christianity.stackexchange.com) and [Biblical Hermeneutics](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com) sites wishing to reference Biblical content in their posts. The content is cleanly formatted as a block-quote, the translation is noted and a link is made back to the relevant Bible Gateway page.

#### Installation

The code is [on github](https://github.com/alerque/biblegateway-markdownifier) and you can [install as a userscript](https://github.com/alerque/biblegateway-markdownifier/raw/master/biblegateway_markdownifier.user.js) or [view the source code](https://github.com/alerque/biblegateway-markdownifier/blob/master/biblegateway_markdownifier.user.js).

Alternate versions are available that use different output formatting from [Jack Douglas](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/users/43/jack-douglas) ([install](https://github.com/jackdouglas/biblegateway-markdownifier/raw/master/biblegateway_markdownifier.user.js), [view](https://github.com/jackdouglas/biblegateway-markdownifier/blob/master/biblegateway_markdownifier.user.js)) and [dancek](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/users/60/dancek) ([install](https://github.com/dancek/biblegateway-markdownifier/raw/master/biblegateway_markdownifier.user.js), [view](https://github.com/dancek/biblegateway-markdownifier/blob/master/biblegateway_markdownifier.user.js)).

#### Example

A box similar to the following will be visible when browsing on the Bible Gateway:

[image: Bible Gateway screenshot]

The contents of that textarea copied into an SE post will produce this formatted output:

[image: Formatted blockquote example]

#### Authors

The original author is [dancek](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/users/60/dancek) whose script [originally debued on the Christianity meta site](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/449/30). The code was released on [his github site](https://github.com/dancek/biblegateway-markdownifier). The version shown above is [my forked copy](https://github.com/alerque/biblegateway-markdownifier) that formats the verse and link output a little bit differently.

#### Changelog

- Version 0.1.3 - *August 5, 2012* - Updated to strip out new stuff recently added to Bible Gateway's markup output.
- Version 0.2.0 - *March 7, 2016* - Updated for new Biblegateway page layout. Thanks to Scott Tomaszewski.

Comment: +1 great to see this going forward! Thanks for forking and putting this up, I'd totally forgotten about the script by now.

Comment: I have updated your script to work with the new layout.  You can find it here: https://github.com/scottTomaszewski/biblegateway-markdownifier

Comment: @Scotty Hey that's awesome man! If you don't mind can we merge your commits upstream? You can either submit a PR (if the Github stats matter) or I can just merge (commits will still show up as yours).

Comment: The updated script from @Scotty worked great for me just now!